# How do i prevent chrome from getting a 'Aw snap!' with Comet?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, google-chrome, comet

I am using Google Chrome for my testing because in the future the comet page will be loaded in google chrome embedded.

After about 12 hours, i guess the comet file gets too big and chrome gets the official:[image: aw snap page]

How do i prevent chrome from as it seems crashing after the page has been up for that long?

Do i have to refresh the iframe?

What i tried is using the comet scripts every 2 minutes i do `$('script').remove()`, so i guess that removes them from the DOM, but the file is still getting bigger...

Can anyone help? ^_^

i will provide as much code as needed if asked. (js, or php)

Comment: Are you bound to using comet? Could you instead take advantage of the built in chrome WebSocket class?

Comment: I have not tried this, but could be useful for php and chrome: http://code.google.com/p/phpwebsocket/

Comment: @Tom we cannot use websocket for security issues

Comment: What security issues are present in websocket?

Comment: @alexy13, just read the wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSockets and just search google for websocket security issues, and ull find alot on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd try to restart the Comet after a while. One hour, or less.

Delete the iframe you where using and `appendChild()` a new one.

Comment: @ZJR thats what i was thinking, but how often should the comet be refreshed, one hour seems too often, no?

Comment: I feel it depends on your application. Considering the kind of things I would apply comet to, (rapid interactions) 1 hour could be a lot. Anyway, it's hard to tell what exactly happens after 12 hours of cometing. You could be hitting some **TCP/IP stack time limit** or some **Chrome memory limit**. If it's TCP, the same Google Chrome on another OS *could* not present the same issue. If it's memory, the due time to refresh depends *on how much data* you actually send in your comet stream. Can you measure that, maybe?

Comment: @ZJR well im going to try every two hours and see if it runs over the weekend. if it does not crash i will get back to u. my comet code is outputting at least one script tag every second

Comment: @ZJR at the moment your answer seems to have worked ^_^, ill get back to this latr today, running tests

Comment: @ZJR, i came back to it 19 hours later and it crashed when i tried using it. (in console)